# Importing reactflow v11 causes error "module parse failed: unexpected token"

Tags: react-flow

When I install [reactflow](https://reactflow.dev) (v11.2.0), I get the following error when I just import anything from that library:

```
./node_modules/@reactflow/minimap/dist/esm/index.js 100:27
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (100:27)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     nodes = _useStore.nodes,
|     rfId = _useStore.rfId;
>   var elementWidth = style?.width ?? defaultWidth;
|   var elementHeight = style?.height ?? defaultHeight;
|   var nodeColorFunc = getAttrFunction(nodeColor);
```

Trying to import the following for example:

```
import ReactFlow, {
    useNodesState,
    useEdgesState,
    addEdge,
    Controls,
    MiniMap,
    useReactFlow,
    ReactFlowProvider,
} from 'reactflow';

import 'reactflow/dist/style.css';
```

This was installed through npm, and I tried deleting package-lock.json and node_modules and reinstall everything but nothing seems to work. Same code use to work fine in v10 (react-flow-renderer), so I suspect this is a bug (?).

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? I'm running into through this exact thing.

Comment: I'm also running into the same issue. I'm going to create this as a bug report in reactflow github repo and link to this stackoverflow since I'm not the only one facing this issue.

My reactflow version is 11.3.2 and I get this error when I try to open it in storybook

Comment: Created issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74423572/importing-reactflow-v11-causes-error-module-parse-failed-unexpected-token

Comment: @whatoncewaslost for some reason when using npm it was not working, when I used yarn as the tool to build it works.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.

I solved it this way

```
install npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@5.0.0
```

Then I deleted the **node_modules** folder, and did the installation again.

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same problem. In my case, [the React version was lower than 17](https://reactflow.dev/docs/guides/migrate-to-v11/).

An upgrade of the React version, or a downgrade to react-flow version 10 solves the problem.

Comment: I upgrade from react 16.13.2 to version 17.0l.0, however I'm still getting this error. Curious if there is anything else I can try?